# How to capture Excel cell borders properly?

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I have added a bottom border to a cell (eg `A1`) using "Format Cells":

[image: Shows cell <code>A1</code> in Excel sheet whose bottom border has been set.]
[`A1` has a bottom border, `A2` has ***no*** border.]

If I then programmatically capture the formatting of cell `A2` *the bottom border of cell `A1`* is captured as *the top border of cell `A2`*.

This is not what happens in native "Format Painter", where copying the format of `A2` to some other cell does not add any border to that target cell - the behavior I am trying to replicate with code.

How to achieve this?

Comment: +1 This could really use to be explained better but this is actually a good question. This is what I understand: Open up Excel, put a bottom border on cell A1. Format-paint A1 to somewhere and you get a bottom border. Format-paint A2 to somewhere and you get no border. If you press Ctrl+1 on cell A1, you see the bottom border as you expect. BUT do the same on cell A2 and *you see a top border*!? This is what I assume the OP is seeing from code as well. So what is Format Painter doing differently?

Comment: You got it, I am trying to mock this behavior of Format Painter, But in my code when I capture cell A2 and apply it somewhere it shows TOP border which is not as per native behaviour. In C# code when I do  selection.Borders[xl.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle it still gives me XlLineStyle.xlContinuous which it should because cell A2 does not have a TOP border whereas cell A1 has a BOTTOM border.

Comment: This is a fascinating question! +1.  If with VBA you set the bottom border of C2, the right border of B3, the left border of D3 and the top border of C4 to double, you will get a properly formatted double border around C3. Using Format Painter, I can copy C2 and its bottom border to another cell. If I then set the top border of C3 to single and use Format Painter to copy C2 again, it has lost its bottom border. I have always accepted that there is a single edge between C2 and C3 like on a sheet of squared paper and it did not matter how it was set.

Comment: Clearly I am correct that there is only one edge between two cells, but Format Painter knows which side it was set from. This is not a problem with C#. The true question is: “How from VBA or via the Interop can you access the information available to Format Painter?”

Comment: @TonyDallimore : sorry for the late reply, you got my question correctly, is there any small hint regarding this ?

Comment: Sorry if my comment implied I knew the solution but wasn’t going to tell you.  I had never tried Format Painter so your question was a revelation for me.  However, I may have a solution although not currently in a form I can share with others.  It is possible to convert an Excel worksheet to Html/Css with Publish Objects but the quality of the Html/Css is so poor that no smart phone can handle it.  _Continued..._

Comment: In response to a Stack Overflow questions, I created a VBA macro which would convert simple to middling complex worksheets to clean Html/Css.  I grew that macro but came to realise the total task was beyond VBA so I switched to VB.Net (C# for wimps).  This allowed me to convert more complex worksheets but the performance was disappointing.  Looking round the forums I found others had hit the same problem.  I found some bizarre approaches but nothing I thought was worth pursuing.  _Continued..._

Comment: I have many years of experience using VBA to extract format information and thought I could do better. I have found a variety of techniques which together get all the necessary information about 100 times faster although not in a convenient format. I am currently struggling to create a convenient format from this jumble of information. What I had not noticed until your question was that I have managed to get the borders in Format Painter style not VBA style. _Continued..._

Comment: This is not an advantage for me because I have an algorithm that converts VBA style border information into Css style border information.  I will have to recode that algorithm; grrrrh!  I cannot post an answer because I have not got a publishable answer.  If you go to my profile you will find an email address.  If this sounds interesting, email me and I will tell you more about what I am doing and how far I have got.

Comment: @TonyDallimore : Extremly sorry for the late reply , the client had changed the requirements so I don't have to work on that anymore, even though I will mail you to get some knowledge on this kind of programming  as it looks you a veteran in this field :), bye see you later

Answer (score 0):

This should be more of a comment, but I don't have access to "comment" yet. The difference between the format painter and what you see when you format the cells is whether you are accessing the `Borders` object or the `range` object. In the borders object, the 2 cells *share* a common border, thus both have the border. However, this border belongs to A1, not A2, so when you copy the **format**, you only get the border when you copy A1.

To mimic this within VBA, you would need to copy A1 and do a PasteSpecial like so:

```
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: You are correct but the problem is I need to preserve the formats ( including Border style ) in the memory as the user might delete the original range or its format and in that case I am not able to get the correct border style ( color etc ) as it is availanle to format painter.